# Create text search block on home page leading to faceted search view?

Tags: blocks, search

This seems like an easy question that seems still unanswered. I have a faceted search in Views. Works nicely. All I want to do is:

1. Create a text field search in a block (can be anywhere, can just use  in a block config for the home page, yes.)
2. Send that text field search right into the faceted search View page.

Seems simple enough and I'm sure many have wanted to do the same? Can anyone help me connect the Drupal dots? Thank you in advance.